# I want to create only one audio player instance

Tags: javascript

I have used the `embed` tag to make a playlist. The player is generated each time you click the audio of the list. When you listen to the selected file and then press one of the other files in the list, the player is eliminated and a new player appears.

However, instead, I want to show only one player, and reuse it.

```
            if (agent.indexOf("chrome") != -1 || agent.indexOf("opera") != -1) {                            
                var audio = document.createElement('audio');
                audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio'); 
                audio.type = 'audio/wav';
                audio.src = files[current];
                audio.autoplay = true;

                a.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(0)');
                a2.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(1)');
                a3.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistClick(2)');

                bottom.appendChild(pop_tit01);
                bottom.appendChild(audio);
                bottom.appendChild(mp3_player);
                bottom.appendChild(re_txt);

            } else {                                        
                var pop_tit01 = document.createElement('dl');
                pop_tit01.setAttribute('class', 'pop_tit01');

                var dt = document.createElement('dt');

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute('src', 'images/img/sample_img05.jpg');

                var dd = document.createElement('dd');

                var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                var str = document.createTextNode("default");
                var strdd = document.createTextNode("click list");

                //top
                dt.appendChild(img);
                strong.appendChild(str);
                dd.appendChild(strong); 
                dd.appendChild(strdd);

                //top image             
                pop_tit01.appendChild(dt);
                pop_tit01.appendChild(dd);  

                bottom.appendChild(pop_tit01);

                a.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(0)');
                a2.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(1)');
                a3.setAttribute('onclick', 'playlistclick(2)');

                //bottom.appendChild(audio);
                bottom.appendChild(re_txt);
            }

            function playlistclick(src) {
                 if (!audio) {
                        audio = document.createElement('embed');
                        audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio');
                        audio.height = "50";
                        audio.width = "400";
                        audio.controls = false;

                        bottom.insertBefore(audio, re_txt);
                      }             
            }
```

Comment: I think you missed some code

Comment: Do you mean you want a single instance of this player? I'm a bit confused by "I would like a new player to appear" and "we want to causing only one of the players", as they sound like opposites...?

Comment: I want to show only one of the players. However, the player keeps occur .

Comment: @takm Looks like it - where is the start of these functions?

Comment: When I select a list. 'playlistclick(0)' or  'playlistclick(1)' or  'playlistclick(2)'

Comment: @takm You have a `}` but no `{` at the start to match it. It looks like you have missed some code from the start of your example.

Comment: The above sources are part of it. Put only the important parts . Because the top is not critical .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time one of the playlists is clicked, you're creating a new audio player, not reusing the old one.

Instead of

```
function playlistclick(src) {
  var audio = document.createElement('embed');
  audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio');
  audio.height = "50";
  audio.width = "400";
  audio.controls = false;

  bottom.insertBefore(audio, re_txt);
  ...
}
```

maybe reuse the audio player thus

```
var audio;

function playlistclick(src) {
  if (!audio) {
    audio = document.createElement('embed');
    audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio');
    audio.height = "50";
    audio.width = "400";
    audio.controls = false;

    bottom.insertBefore(audio, re_txt);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: To modify the source raised again.

Comment: @takm, I don't undertand your comment.  Could you please rephrase.

Comment: Revised on the source . Please look again